# Qt - Why unable read file using QFile with directory which get from FileDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, qml, qtquick2

I'm reading a file on Qt 5.12 using QFile. I try to read a file from my computer but when I using the directory which read from FileDialog has "file:///" prefix. Can anyone tell me why is it wrong and how to using URL which gets form FileDialog, please?

Thanks!

```qt
QFile file("C:/Users/HuuChinhPC/Desktop/my_txt.txt"); // this work
//QFile file("file:///C:/Users/HuuChinhPC/Desktop/my_txt.txt"); //didn't work
QString fileContent;
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
    QString line;
    QTextStream t( &file );
    do {
        line = t.readLine();
        fileContent += line;
     } while (!line.isNull());

    file.close();
} else {
    emit error("Unable to open the file");
    return QString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileDialog` returns a url since in QML that type of data is used, but QFile not so you must convert the `QUrl` to a used string `toLocalFile()`:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString readFile(const QUrl & url){
    if(!url.isLocalFile()){
        Q_EMIT error("It is not a local file");
        return {};
    }
    QFile file(url.toLocalFile());
    QString fileContent;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
        QString line;
        QTextStream t( &file );
        do {
            line = t.readLine();
            fileContent += line;
         } while (!line.isNull());
        file.close();
        return fileContent;
    } else {
        Q_EMIT error("Unable to open the file");
        return {};
    }
}
```

***.qml**

```
var text = helper.readFile(fileDialog.fileUrl)
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to strip the file prefix to use the URL which gets form FileDialog:

```
QFile file("file:///C:/Users/HuuChinhPC/Desktop/my_txt.txt")
if (Qt.platform.os === "windows") {
    return file.replace(/^(file:\/{3})|(file:)|(qrc:\/{3})|(http:\/{3})/,"")
}
else {
    return file.replace(/^(file:\/{2})|(qrc:\/{2})|(http:\/{2})/,"");
}
```